# What is a friendly way to say ' Now processing'?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm developing software something like iPhone's 'Siri'. If I call its name, it will answer,

> What can I help you with?

If I say "Turn on the TV", it will answer,

> Now Processing ...

But, I think "Now processing ..." doesn't sound friendly. So, isn't there a more friendly way to say "Now processing"? For example,

> I'm turning on TV, processing, please wait

Comment: Processing is a generic word just like "working", which mean nothing specific. Hold music has the right connotation without using words, only kidding. Response times should be near real time, so there should be no need for "Now Processing" and instead should be "turning on TV". Just realised you have another pause after processing "Please wait". Does this app really work or just makes people waste time? Awaiting input, input received, processing input, please wait, establishing parameters, thank you [nothing happens]. If you really must "Baking commands" or "As you wish, M-A-S-T-E-R".

Comment: This question would be better answered on [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "Making it so...", with a suitable accent, please.

Comment: At your service?

Comment: "If I had a faster processor I wouldn't have to say anything here."

Comment: I'm not sure this question is suitable — it's just asking for opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Since achris already claimed "as you wish" (skip the master!), how about:

- Coming right up!
- Just a minute
- Wait for it...
- Your wish is my command
- Say please!

Comment: These are good (except for the last one!). I also like: _"I'm on it..."_

Comment: @kristina ...dary :D

Comment: @Ranger, sorry, I'm not understanding your comment.  What am I missing? :-/

Comment: @KristinaLopez, you aren't missing anything. i was just referring to the famous phrase(wait for it...) from HIMYM Tv Serial.

Comment: @Ranger, gotcha. Lol!

Answer (score 0):

Forget friendly and be precise. Why not use "**Loading...**"?

Comment: @RegDwighT: I indeed meant to write the phrase "**Loading...**". The question mark at the end would kill its purpose.